# 'undefined' output in array object - nodejs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

Output from:

```
console.log(response);
console.log(response[0].group_id);
```

is as below:

```
[{"group_id":8}]
undefined
```

what is wrong here? How do I access the value for "group_id" i.e. 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the content in `response` is a string and not a JSON object.

I suggest to parse the object using `JSON`, like so:

```
const o = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(o[0]);
console.log(o[0].group_id);
```

What you suggested (`response[0].group_id`) definitely should return `8` in case `response` is a JSON object. If you try this code below:

```
const o = JSON.parse("[{\"group_id\":8}]");
console.log(o[0]);
console.log(o[0].group_id);
```

You will get this output:

```
{ group_id: 8 }
8
```

Comment: To be sure that the problem is the one suggested by @gil.fernandes, use of : `console.log(typeof response)`. If it returns `"string"` it means that `response` is not an json object but a regular string.

Comment: This one worked:
**console.log(JSON.parse(response)[0].group_id)**
to give the output - 8